# List is fading and sliding, instead of only fading and a div above sliding

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slide

I have a two divs, one is just a text with 'logo' class and the second is a list. When an element inside list is clicked, the list should fade out and logo should slide a certain pixels up.

Here is my HTML for that bit :

```
<nav class='mainnav'>
  <div class='logo'>logo</div>
  <div class='listcontainer'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>first link</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='second'>second link</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>third link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.second').click(function(){
        $('.listcontainer').fadeOut('slow');
        $('.logo').animate({'height':'300px'},'slow');
    });
});
```

With this code, list is sliding down and fading at the same time. How to make list only fading and logo only sliding down?

Comment: If I may suggest, with **[TimelineMax](http://greensock.com/timelinemax)**, which is part of **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)** suite of tools, you get a lot of control. Take a look at the **[examples](http://greensock.com/examples-showcases)**, the **[collections](http://codepen.io/collection/wDliL/)**  at codepen or read the **[documentation](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/)**, you will be pleasantly surprised. **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/ns776u3c/)** is an example I just created.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use the `fadeOut()` callback function here :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LprVvM?editors=001)

```
$(function () {

    $('.second').click(function() {

        $('.listcontainer').fadeOut('slow', function() {

             $('.logo').animate({height: 300}, 'slow');
        });;
    });
 });
```

Otherwise it will be executed at the same time as `.animate()` (asynchronously).

Answer (score 0):

The list is "sliding" down because you are increasing the space of the element above (the logo).  To make the list fade finish before the div expands, use the `.promise().done()` function on the fadeout:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.second').click(function () {
         $('.listcontainer').fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function () {
             $('.logo').animate({
                 'height': '300px'
             }, 'slow');
         });;
     });
 });
```